# How to list all the running processes by using UNIX-C/C++

Tags: linux, unix

I want to list all of the processes in the system. I used to use shell command "ps" and system function to get the result. However, it seems a little complex. How to use UNIX C functions to complete this job.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux you can examine the pseudo filesystem `/proc` for process information.  That means using the `opendir()` set of functions and looking for sub-directories that are numbers - these are the process identifiers of each of the processes running on the system.  There are numerous files within each sub-directory, that can be opened and read using `open()/read()` as long as your process has the required privileges.

See the

> proc(5)

manpage for more details of the information available to you.

Answer (score 3):

While you're definitely encouraged to browse the pseudo `/proc` filesystem, from a C/C++ program you should be using `proc/readproc.h` that is part of `libprocps` and is capable of accessing the same information.

E.g. on Debian based distribution you'll need to install `libprocps-dev`:

```
apt install libprocps-dev
```

You can list your processes this way, see `man openproc` for available flags:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <proc/readproc.h>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
  PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS);

  proc_t proc_info;
  memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));
  cout << "Program\tPID\tPPID\tMEM\tutime\tstime\n";
  while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
      cout << proc_info.cmd << "\t" << proc_info.tid;
      cout << proc_info.ppid << "\t" << proc_info.resident;
      cout << proc_info.utime << "\t" << proc_info.stime << "\n";
  }

  closeproc(proc);

  return 0;
}
```

and compile it:

```
g++ -g -Wall -O2 readps.cc -o readps -lprocps
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a finish solution for this.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/readproc/code/ci/master/tree/

clone it using git and do what you want.

```c
#include"read_proc.h"
int main(void)
{
   struct Root * root=read_proc();
   struct Job * buffer;
   int i=0;
   for(;i<root->len;i++)
   {
       buffer=get_from_place(root,i);
       printf("%s\t%u\n",buffer->name,buffer->pid);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the sourceforge server is currently down.

Answer (score 1):

*ps* [is the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ps.html), for better or worse.  It has many under-appreciated formatting options that can simplify your cross-platform parsing of its output.

`/proc` is more convenient, but not portable, and might be unavailable locally even where supported (e.g., in a *chroot* environment).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to list `/proc/` directory =) My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291422/quantify-ram-cpu-use-of-a-process-in-c-under-linux) may be somewhat helpful for you.

Comment: No such thing as a *folder* on Unix.

Comment: @tchrist, please, be more specific

Comment: Unix has directories, not folders. Folders sounds like baby-talk to us.

Comment: @shybovycha. tchrist was wrong anyway. In Unix there are no directories either - only files.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standards for finding process information; each Unix vendor gets to provide their own mechanism for providing information to system administrators.

Linux and Solaris use the `/proc/` filesystem to export information on processes to userspace, but I do not think they are at all compatible. (I have a vague recollection that Solaris decided to export all its information in a binary format to remove in-kernel processing, at the expense of more closely tying userspace programs to kernel datastructures. The `top` program used to be very good at peeking into kernel memory to read process tables, I'm not sure it needs to any more, but maybe all the historical knowledge is still baked in.)

If you want to be platform-specific, the Linux `proc(5)` manpage has the information you need. Happy hacking. :)

Comment: Also, BSD systems use a reduced or different procfs layout, if they use it at all. This includes MacOS *née* Darwin.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page of ps I read that you can use `ps -e` to list all the processes in standard format and use `ps ax` to list all the processes in BSD format.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#assume target running /root/eclipse_android/targetname/targetname usb 1 2 3
#here list all process and get args
#

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <ctype.h>
static int is_Pid_Dir(const struct dirent* entry)
{
    const char* p;

    for (p = entry->d_name; *p; p++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*p))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static void List_Command()
{
    char            szProc[256];
    char            szFullLine[256];
    char            szCmd[256];
    char            szType[64];
    int             iLocationId;
    int             iAction;
    int             iCount;
    int             iHit;
    size_t          stCmdLen;
    char*           szName;
    FILE*           fp;
    DIR*            dProcPath;
    struct  dirent* entry;

    // Open /proc directory.
    dProcPath = opendir("/proc");

    if (dProcPath)
    {
        // Iterate through all files and directories of /proc.
        while ((entry = readdir(dProcPath)))
        {
            // Skip anything that is not a PID directory.
            if (is_Pid_Dir(entry))
            {
                //if want all status open /proc/<PID>/status
                //if want get cmdline open /proc/<PID>/cmdline
                snprintf(szProc, sizeof(szProc), "/proc/%s/cmdline", entry->d_name);

                fp = fopen(szProc, "r");
                if (fp)
                {
                    // Get PID, process name and number of faults.
                    //fscanf(fp, "%s %s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*lu %*lu %lu", &pid, &szProc, &maj_faults);
                    memset(szFullLine, 0x00, sizeof(szFullLine));

                    stCmdLen = fread(szFullLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(szFullLine), fp);
                    fclose(fp);

                    if( stCmdLen > 0 )
                    {
                        szName = strstr(szFullLine, "targetname");
                        if( szName )
                        {
                            iHit = 0;
                            for(iCount=0; iCount<stCmdLen-1; iCount++)
                            {
                                if( szFullLine[iCount] == '\x00' )
                                {
                                    iHit++;
                                    szFullLine[iCount] = ' ';
                                }
                            }

                            //sscanf("19 cool kid", "%d %[^\n]", &iCount, szType);
                            if( iHit >= 3 )
                            {
                                sscanf(szFullLine, "%[^' '] %[^' '] %d %d", szCmd, szType, &iLocationId, &iAction);
                                printf("%s %s %d %d\n", szCmd, szType, iLocationId, iAction);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dProcPath);
}
```

also cpp: https://cplusplus.com/forum/unices/221977/

download https://busybox.net/downloads/

extract and trace ps.c, procps.c full api
procps_status_t* FAST_FUNC procps_scan(procps_status_t* sp, int flags)